# Overridden AccountController now Forgotten password not working

Tags: customer, customer-account, password-recovery

I've overridden the AccountController.php, but by doing so customers who reset their password, click on the link in the email and are instantly shown an error of :

**Your password reset link has expired.**

If I remove the override the reset work fine.

Any ideas what I can do?

Thanks

P.S the account override is needed.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pts_RegisterInCheckout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pts_RegisterInCheckout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <registerincheckout before="Mage_Customer">Pts_RegisterInCheckout</registerincheckout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <registerincheckout module="registerincheckout">
                    <file>registerincheckout.xml</file>
                </registerincheckout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <registerincheckout>
                <class>Pts_RegisterInCheckout_Block</class>
            </registerincheckout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**AccountController.php**

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';

class Pts_RegisterInCheckout_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{

    /**
     * Customer register form page
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*');
            return;
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Create customer account action
     */
    public function createPostAction()
    {
        /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $errUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true));
            $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
            return;
        }

        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();

        try {
            $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);

            if (empty($errors)) {
                $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
                $customer->save();
                $this->_dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer);
                $this->_successProcessRegistration($customer);
                return;
            } else {
                $this->_addSessionError($errors);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = $this->_getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
        }
        $errUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true));
        $this->_redirectError($errUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code of what you have done so we can see what might be the issue. Post your config.xml and controller for example

Comment: in AccountController.php use this : require_once("Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php");

Comment: As long as you don't re-define the method for resetting customer password, you shouldn't be seeing the problem you mentioned. There must be something else causing the problem. Any possibility of any extension re-writing the same controller file ?